# Tail of selection of tuples within union

Tags: typescript

Say I have a union of tuples, `U`.

```
type T1 = [1,'a', boolean];
type T2 = [1,'b','c'];
type T3 = ['c','a'];
type T4=[3]
type T5=[3,'a']

type U = [T1,T2,T3,T4,T5][number]
```

and a tail type, `Tail`.

```
type Tail<T extends readonly unknown[]> = T extends readonly [
  unknown,
  ...infer TailType
]
  ? TailType
  : never;
```

Is there a way I can get the tail for a selection of tuples from the union, according to, for example, the first element in the tuple.

For the above example, and for the first element with value `1`, I would like to get `["a", boolean] | ["b", "c"]`. For value `c`, get `['a']` and for `3` to get `["a"] | []`.

Guess this could be broken down into first selecting tuples from union and then just perform tail but any suggestions are great. Thank you.

Typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2nANAcgIafVAIwHsiAbCbAOwF0BuAKFElgCYlUNMC9MBjTOo3DQYAZnYo%20PXIKYiALIhSjqQ5jACsS0Vhn010AKoT46GCzM6Y8sxuopKAVwC2BCACdVB2NgCWpAB4YKAgAD2AISgATAGcodwoookpSEChHSgBrSiIAd0oUagA%20dmCwiOi4hOwklLSUeih0rJz89EaoADpu30oAMw8ffxhhelUmgH4h0hHIDoAuKEoIADcPBn05KAB1Ur9AwyKgA) as a starting point

Comment: `[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5][number]` is just a weird and verbose way to write `T1 | T2 | T3 | T4 | T5` right?

Comment: yea pretty much ahahha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Extract` which is documented as:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
// Extract from T those types that are assignable to U
```

So `Extract<U, [1, ...unknown[]]>` is `T1 | T2`

Which means you can do:

```
type W = Tail<Extract<U, [1, ...unknown[]]>>
// ["a", boolean] | ["b", "c"]
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA2nANAcgIafVAIwHsiAbCbAOwF0BuAKFElgCYlUNMC9MBjTOo3DQYAZnYo+PXIKYiALIhSjqQ5jACsS0Vhn010AKrt4UAD6tzscRZjyrm-XNjYAlqQA8MKBAAewCEoAEwBnKAAnCiCiSlIQKABXSgBrSiIAd0oUagA+Ex9-QNCIqJi41HooRJS0zPRKqAA6ZtdKADMIcJd3GGF6VSqAfm7SXsgGgC4oSggAN06GAygAQXYAUX9w7F5gD0N8NHxmxqTUjKzqXKdhKAB1EzdPDeAtnb2DjCbm09qL3Jz6AB6QFVKAAPUGQA)